# How to do conditional grouping in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My records are --

```html
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980edf0523e2bf6ff12937b"), "RecordNumber":"R1", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SAPNumber" : "W12345678" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937c"), "RecordNumber":"R2", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SAPNumber" : "W12345678" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee47523e2bf6ff129380"), "RecordNumber":"R3", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SAPNumber" : "W12345679", "PONumber" : "P9888" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937d"), "RecordNumber":"R4", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937e"), "RecordNumber":"R5", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SalesNumber" : "SO1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937f"), "RecordNumber":"R6", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SalesNumber" : "SO1" }
```

This is what i need --
The records need to be grouped first based on "SAPNumber", if its not available then based on "PONumber", 
if that is also not available then based on "SalesNumber".

So R1 and R2 should be grouped in the same group because they have the same "SAPNumber".

But R3 should be in a different group as it has a different "SAPNumber".

Now, for R4 and R5, since they do not have a "SAPNumber" so they should be grouped based on "PONumber". Since they have the same "PONumber" as R1 and R2,
so they should be in the same group as R1 and R2.

Now R6 does not have a "SAPNumber" or "PONumber", so it should be grouped based on "SalesNumber", and since it has the same "SalesNumber" as R5, 
so they should be in the same group.
Meaning R1, R2, R4, R5, and R6 should all be in the same group, and R3 in a different group.
After adding "GroupID", Output should be like --

```html
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980edf0523e2bf6ff12937b"), "RecordNumber":"R1", "GroupID":"G1", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SAPNumber" : "W12345678"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937c"), "RecordNumber":"R2", "GroupID":"G1", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SAPNumber" : "W12345678"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937d"), "RecordNumber":"R4", "GroupID":"G1", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937e"), "RecordNumber":"R5", "GroupID":"G1", "PONumber" : "P9888", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SalesNumber" : "SO1"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee46523e2bf6ff12937f"), "RecordNumber":"R6", "GroupID":"G1", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SalesNumber" : "SO1"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5980ee47523e2bf6ff129380"), "RecordNumber":"R3", "GroupID":"G2", "ImportBatchID" : "9876", "SAPNumber" : "W12345679", "PONumber" : "P9888"}
```

Can youn please guide me how to do it ? I tried doing it using aggregation but was not successful. 
Can it be done using MapReduce. If yes, what should be the code like ? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're not doing any grouping here in the sense that there is no aggregation in your expected output. It seems to me that the only difference between the input & the output is the extra `GroupID` field. I would think that this logic is best implemented in the application layer instead of the database layer.

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha Thats right. I want to group it based on the logic i mentioned and add the same groupid to the same group of transactions. Do you think the best way to do it in the application layer ?

Comment: I think what you want to do is somewhat similar to a stored procedure in SQL, which MongoDB as of 3.4.6 doesn't have a direct equivalent of. If your intent is to add a "group" field to the documents (by mutating them as you described), then the application layer is likely the best place to do this. However, if you require some form of aggregated result (count, sum, etc.) then MongoDB can do that.

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha I took your advice and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.